# How to get content uri from file?

Tags: java, android, file, uri

I'm using this code which works, but i was wondering if there is a simpler way to get the content uri?

**My code**

```
 MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getActivity(), new String[]{songFile.getAbsolutePath()}, null,
                        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.d("test", "content Uri: " + uri); //Here i get my content Uri
                    } 

 });
```

**songFile value:**

```
songFile: /storage/emulated/0/Music/$UICIDEBOY$ - Carrollton.mp3
```

**Content Uri when using MediaScannerConnection**

```
content://media/external_primary/file/24
```

Comment: Using a lambda would at least make the code more compact.

Comment: @chrylis But what i'm using now is recommended or is there a better way? I see alot of posts just using Uri.fromFile but that returns file:/// and not content://

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Android to say, but I would not be surprised if this callback approach were the simplest option.